# Best practices for unit tests on androidTest to access a large number of test files

Tags: android, unit-testing

I need to access a lot of external test files in my `androidTest`. if I put them in `androidTest/assets` directory as asset or resource, it will result in a very large compiled unitest apk, which is very time consuming to compile and install.

In the past, the ideal way was to manually copy the corresponding files to /sdcard as a precondition for testing.

However, newer android versions require additional permissions and granting actions for accessing the sdcard.

Adding the corresponding permissions to `androidManifest.xml` would go against the origin needs of the application. This is because the application under test does not have a need for that permission and has it only for testing purposes.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to give you an exact solution because it strongly depends on your specific context like for instance:

- how these test files are produced,
- do they change frequently,
- where these files are stored (cloud or other systems),
- are the tests executed on CI or locally,
- are the tests executed on an emulator or real device

... and so on.

That said, you can evaluate the following solutions:

- provide these files through a rest API letting the tests access that endpoint to retrieve the files. This of course has the drawback of increasing the overall time taken to execute the tests (since the tests need to download the files)
- or, build a custom emulator instance (or docker instance) where you pre-propulate the image with the test files and located them in a folder openly accessible without special permission (like for instance `/sdcard/Documents` or `/data/local/tmp` or in the app's private area)